# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Payment' not found in

Tags: php, apache, paypal, get

Help guys! getting error as said in the title. Been trying to figure it out but i haven't found any helpful answered as of now. Thank you.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Payment' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\pay.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\paypal\pay.php on line 19

```
<?php

use Paypal\Api\Payment;
use Paypal\Api\PaymentExecution;

require 'app/start.php';

if(!isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentId'],$_GET['PayerID'])) {
   die();
 }

if ((bool)$_GET['success'] === false){
   die();
}

$paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
$payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);
$execute = new PaymentExecution();
$execute->setPayerId($payerId);

try {
    $result = $payment -> execute($execute, $paypal);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are missing `include "vendor/autoload.php"`

Comment: I think not, it's already required in the start.php
 <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost/paypal');

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
 new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
  'Ac2Bf5_3FJo_vbWtx_l51xddnVcZPV_kaHXnmZtDca1BNEslDu9fAK_QzFLfaf51AYVOAm43c9wCQ8Nw'
  ,
  'EF2a0vQXlL-WjATepM6fmYOtHnBybKeghLiid38RVcXULFZttviQiNzoX6vmVOudkoVRyphKwo826st6'
  )
);

Comment: then try putting that start.php at top .. but i don't think this would help. Check if your vendor/autoload  is actually being loaded.